# In Spree 2.0.3 , How would I remove shipping address in Spree checkout routine?

Tags: spree

I tried to create app/models/spree/order_decorator.rb as :
Spree::Order.class_eval do
   checkout_flow do
     go_to_state :address
        go_to_state :payment, :if => lambda { |order| order.payment_required? }
        go_to_state :confirm, :if => lambda { |order| order.confirmation_required? }
        go_to_state :complete
        remove_transition :from => :delivery, :to => :confirm
      end
end

but this code only removes delivery process , I think I have to make some changes in order model but that was too complicated for me , anybody pls help me out for what are changes has to be done to achieve this ?

Also I have to remove validation for shipping method..so that i can go next page of check out flow.

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you reviewed the docs on the checkout flow API?

http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/checkout.html

Comment: it's a spree issue rite now .
https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/2571
I fix it using some hack but it was not a code fix .